# Angular TypeScript state controller

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to attach a controller to a state (using angular ui.router) and I don't understand why writing it one way works, but not the other.

Working example (with the controller registered against the module):

```
this.$stateProvider
  .state('items', {
    url: '/{cluster}/items',
    templateUrl: App.mapPath('Items/Items.html'),
    controller: 'ItemsController as controller'
   });
```

but this doesn't (with an 'anonymous' controller):

```
this.$stateProvider
  .state('items', {
    url: '/{cluster}/items',
    templateUrl: App.mapPath('Items/Items.html'),
    controller: ItemsController,
    controllerAs: 'controller'
  });
```

Keep in mind that my controller has dependencies:

```
export class ItemsController {
  static $inject = ['$scope', 'itemsResource', '$stateParams'];
  constructor(
    scope: IItemsScope,
    itemsFactory: IItemsResource,
    stateParams: IClustersStateParams) {
     scope.items = itemsFactory.query({ cluster: stateParams.cluster });
   }

  public newItem(): void {
    console.log('test');
  }
}
```

My Items.html template is:

```
<div class="items">
  <ul class="add">
    <li>
      <action icon-style="glyphicon-plus" text="Add new item" activated="controller.newItem()"></action>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items">
      <item item="item"></item>
    </li>
  </ul>
  </div>
```

And the `action` directive:

```
export class ActionDirective implements ng.IDirective {
  restrict = 'E';
  replace = true;
  template = '<a class="action"><span class="glyphicon {{iconStyle}}" aria-hidden="true"></span><span>{{text}}</span></a>';
  scope = {
    iconStyle: '@iconStyle',
    text: '@text',
    activated: '&'
  };

  public link(scope: IActionDirectiveScope, instanceElement: ng.IAugmentedJQuery, instanceAttributes: ng.IAttributes, controller: any): void
  {
    instanceElement.on('click', (): void => {
    scope.activated();
    });
  }

public static factory(): ng.IDirectiveFactory {
  const directive = () => new ActionDirective();

  return directive;
}
```

}

The issue is the `controller.newItem()` call. In the working example it will work correctly, otherwise it won't display anything to the console. Also I've noticed the `items` array (set in the controller's constructor) will always be populated (regardless of the approach), so it's ONLY a matter of calling `controller.newItem()` that won't work ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass the controller as a STRING name:

```
this.$stateProvider
  .state('items', {
    url: '/{cluster}/items',
    templateUrl: App.mapPath('Items/Items.html'),
    //controller: ItemsController,
    controller: "ItemsController",
    controllerAs: 'controller'
  })
```

as described in the doc http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider

> **`controller`**: Controller `fn` that should be associated with newly related scope **or the name of a registered controller if passed as a string**. Optionally, the ControllerAs may be declared here.

But we can path just the constructor function (class name) as well.

#### There is [a working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/bCztfw6NVHxnDTPbNxyc?p=preview).

I placed controller into the namespace:

```
namespace MyModule{
 export class ItemsController {
  static $inject = ['$scope', 'itemsResource', '$stateParams'];
  constructor(
    scope: IItemsScope,
    itemsFactory: IItemsResource,
    stateParams: IClustersStateParams) {
     scope.items = itemsFactory.query({ cluster: stateParams.cluster });
   }

  public newItem(): void {
    console.log('test');
  }
 }
}
```

check [it here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=namespace%20MyModule%7B%0A%20export%20class%20ItemsController%20%7B%0A%20%20static%20%24inject%20%3D%20%5B'%24scope'%2C%20'itemsResource'%2C%20'%24stateParams'%5D%3B%0A%20%20constructor(%0A%20%20%20%20scope%3A%20IItemsScope%2C%0A%20%20%20%20itemsFactory%3A%20IItemsResource%2C%0A%20%20%20%20stateParams%3A%20IClustersStateParams)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20scope.items%20%3D%20itemsFactory.query(%7B%20cluster%3A%20stateParams.cluster%20%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20public%20newItem()%3A%20void%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log('test')%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%7D%0A%7D)

And with this state def:

```
.state('items', {
    url: '/{cluster}/items',
    //templateUrl: App.mapPath('Items/Items.html'),
    templateUrl: 'Items/Items.html',
    controller: MyModule.ItemsController, 
    controllerAs: 'controller'
})
```

And this view Items/Items.html

```
<div class="items">
 ...
      <button icon-style="glyphicon-plus" text="Add new item" >xxx
 ..
</div>
```

we can see it is working. [Check it here](http://plnkr.co/edit/bCztfw6NVHxnDTPbNxyc?p=preview)

Comment: In this case, I don't want to register the controller with the module (I've registered it just to get it working). This state is the only usage so I'd rather just specify it on the fly...

Comment: I am using both (typescript and UI-Router) and would discourage you from this approach (the one you want). Just try to do it the native angular way. Register controller, declare dependencies (`static $inject = [...]`) and let controller live its life. Join it to state just via its string name (IoC). this way you can test it - independently from the state...

Comment: Ok, it's good enough, but I still don't understand why the difference and that's why I've posted the question...

Comment: I extended my answer, and showed that your approach (I would not go that way) is working. I added links to working plunker and provided more details. hope it could help you a bit... good luck with TS and UI-Router ;)

Comment: Thanks, I was just being dumb reading the documentation, it's clearly stated how is should work (as you've highlighted)...

Comment: This is great info. Enjoy mighty UI-Router ;)